# Spring wildcard not working

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using maven, and included my config file under src/main/resources as "singleton-config.xml".

When I am creating context as

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:singleton-config.xml");
```

it is working fine but when I use wildcard

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:singleton-*.xml");
```

It is giving exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'singleton' is defined.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wildcard after the classpath ("classpath*")

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:singleton-*.xml");
```

**Explanation**

> **The Classpath*: portability classpath*: prefix**
>
> When constructing an XML-based application context, a location string
>   may use the special classpath*: prefix:

```
ApplicationContext ctx =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:conf/appContext.xml");
```

> This special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match
>   the given name must be obtained (internally, this essentially happens
>   via a ClassLoader.getResources(…​) call), and then merged to form the
>   final application context definition.

See [Wildcards in application context constructor resource paths](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths) for more information.

Comment: Can you explain please why classpath* ??

Comment: I added it to my answer.